# Secured data upload to Aircraft over ARINC 615A

Tags: authentication, integrity, data-validation

We have a requirement for Data loading function to Aircraft. There is Avionics standard termed as ARINC 615A and ARINC 665. 615A specifies high speed Ethernet based data load operation; where POINT-TO-POINT Ethernet connection between Data loader device and target machine in Aircraft.

Since ARINC 615A doesn't seem to provide a full proof secured communication (uses and TFTP protocol over UDP/IP and CRC check), we intend to make this function fully secured. We however would be using underlying standard protocol of 615A & 665; and intend to build additional security on top of it.

Confidentiality is not a concern here; so we don't need to encrypt the data which is being transmitted.

Our primary intent is to address Authenticity and Integrity!
This is a point to point Ethernet connection and not connected to internet or any other network. however threat we want to address is if a malicious data loader machine is connected which loads the malicious data to aircraft.

What should be a good measure to build additional security on top of underlying 615A protocol?

Digitally signing the data with a digital certificate could be a option that we are considering? but will that be a good option as this is not a internet connected set up to validate the certificate etc.

Comment: The usual answer is don't build your own system. Use existing protocols like TLS, or in this case D-TLS since UDP. Your transport framing will be different, but you can encapsulate DTLS messages in any other transport.

Comment: Thanks Steve! can D-TLS be implemented here in this scenario (2 nodes connected over point to point ethernet over IP protocol)?

Comment: Yes. D/TLS is transport independent.